# How can I relate a Yii Model to itself?

Tags: mysql, yii, relational-database

I have two tables:

```
tags
---
id
name
etc..

tags_synonyms
---
tag_id
syn_id
```

The syn_id is the synonym tag's id, and the tag_id reflects the "root" tag that will actually be used. The synonyms exist only to provide alternative spelling/etc for tags to reference and find the root tag through. (please correct me if they should be stored in a separate table)

So I created a model Tag in Yii, but I'm not sure how to setup the relationships for it.

What I want to be able to do is do:
$tag->synonyms, and $tag->root to grab all synonyms and the one root tag respectively.

How would I setup the relationships for these two things?

Comment: one tag_synonym can be a synonym for only one root_tag? i.e tags can be either of type synonym or root, right?

Comment: So far I think that's all it needs to be; a word is either a root word with synonyms, or a synonym with one root word. What I'd like to do is scan text for all the words (root and synonym) and then only store the root words as tags.

Comment: so have you already made the db table, have you thought about how you will relate the two fields in the same table(i.e tags table)?

Comment: I had planned to make them both related to the id column in tags, but I'm open to suggestions on how this /should/ be accomplished

Comment: alright, then you want help with the relations function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a linked_to root word column to the tags table and using that to reference the main word from the synonyms.

Answer (score 0):

just check this link..to know more about how relationships are made in Yii Framework
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/post.model#customizing-x-16x-method

Relation should be declared in `TagsSynonyms model`

```
public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'synonymstags' => array(self::BELONGS_TO,'TagsSynonyms','tag_id'),
    );
  }
```

Relation should be declared in `Tags model`

```
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'tags' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Tags', 'tag_id'),
    );
  }
```

Comment: That's what I thought initially, but I don't know if it's the best answer to create another model for this; it seems like I'd be abusing the Model structure just to create a connection from Tags back to itself